# Bootstrap form elements - in-line group not working as expected

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code to build a small in-line form group but it doesn't display properly.

It displays perfectly in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/topz45ot/4/) but on my webpage, it shows like this:

[image: Form display]

```
  <form role="form" runat="server">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn input-group-lg">
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddreg" CssClass="form-control input-lg" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="<Select>" Value="0" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Enter any comments..." />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Add</button>
                        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- /.input-group -->
  </div>
</form>
```

The HTML source is outputted as follows:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn input-group-lg">
          <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddreg" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddreg" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="0">&lt;Select&gt;</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

</select>
                        </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Enter any comments..." />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Add</button>
                        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- /.input-group -->
  </div>
```

This all goes into an `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` block, which is in my master page like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Page content here -->
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
  <hr />

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2016.</p>
  </footer>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: When you run your project on local host and hit f12 on the keyboard to bring up the development tools and inspect the element what does it tell you?

Comment: It shows a width of 1% for the `span` element. However if I remove that, it puts the `dropdown` above the `comments` box at 100% width, which is also wrong.

Comment: This might seem obvious but there are no custom style sheets unexpectedly overriding the element?

Comment: There are some styles on the jsfiddle which kind of improve the layout but make the dropdown too wide. Apart from that it's just the boostrap css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of lets see what documentation for input groups states: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

> Textual `<input>`s only
>
> Avoid using `<select>` elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.
>
> Avoid using `<textarea>` elements here as their rows attribute will not be respected in some cases.

So now we need to scrape use of select component, and use button drop downs for example:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

If you are unable to use button drop down lets see if we can do this with bootstrap grid?

```
<form class="form my-form">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddreg" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddreg" class="form-control input-lg">
                <option value="0">&lt;Select&gt;</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
             </select>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Close, but we need to get rid of that rounded corners and to make sure that all elements are same height:

```
.my-form .input-lg, .my-form .btn-lg {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  height: 42px !important;
}
```

```css
.my-form .input-lg,
.my-form .btn-lg {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  height: 42px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form my-form">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddreg" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddreg" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="0">&lt;Select&gt;</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="comments" placeholder="Enter any comments...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is all css needed for this form, I also added `!important` marker as asp.net knows to play with input sizes in nasty way.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. I think I'm there now! :)